# Very nested JSON with optional fields into pandas dataframe

Tags: python, json, pandas, dataframe, dictionary

I have a JSON with the following structure. I want to extract some data to different lists so that I will be able to transform them into a pandas dataframe.

```
{
    "ratings": {
        "like": {
            "average": null,
            "counts": {
                "1": {
                    "total": 0,
                    "users": []
                }
            }
        }
    },
    "sharefile_vault_url": null,
    "last_event_on": "2021-02-03 00:00:01",
    ],
    "fields": [
        {
            "type": "text",
            "field_id": 130987800,
            "label": "Name and Surname",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": "John Smith"
                }
            ],
        {
            "type": "category",
            "field_id": 139057651,
            "label": "Gender",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "status": "active",
                        "text": "Male",
                        "id": 1,
                        "color": "DCEBD8"
                    }
                }
            ],
        {
            "type": "category",
            "field_id": 151333010,
            "label": "Field of Studies",
            "values": [
                {
                    "value": {
                        "status": "active",
                        "text": "Languages",
                        "id": 3,
                        "color": "DCEBD8"
                    }
                }
            ],
       }
}
```

For example, I create a list

```
names = []
```

where if "label" in the "fields" list is "Name and Surname" I append `["values"][0]["value"]` so `names` now contains "John Smith". I do exactly the same for the "Gender" label and append the value to the list `genders`.

The above dictionary is contained in a list of dictionaries so I just have to loop though the list and extract the relevant fields like this:

```py
names = []
genders = []

for r in range(len(users)):
    for i in range(len(users[r].json()["items"])):
        for field in users[r].json()["items"][i]["fields"]:
            if field["label"] == "Name and Surname":
                names.append(field["values"][0]["value"])
            elif field["label"] == "Gender":
                genders.append(field["values"][0]["value"]["text"])
            else:
                 # Something else
```

where `users` is a list of responses from the API, each JSON of which has the `items` is a list of dictionaries where I can find the `field` key which has as the value a list of dictionaries of different fields (like Name and Surname and Gender).

The problem is that the dictionary with "label: Field of Studies" is optional and is not always present in the list of fields.

How can I manage to check for its presence, and if so append its value to a list, and `None` otherwise?

Answer (score 0):

To me it seems that the data you have is not valid JSON. However if I were you I would try using [**pandas.json_normalize**](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/reference/api/pandas.json_normalize.html). According to the documentation this function will put `None` if it encounters an object with a label not inside it.